# Can't start/boot Elementry OS loki after fresh install

Tags: release-loki, boot

I have installed Loki with update on the go when installing but when restart can't load into OS, can't show the splash just like typing but nothing to do. I have installed dual boot with Windows10 and installed grub in sda5. How to fix it? Please help me???[image: boot error]

Comment: Did you install a boot loader in /dev/sda?

Comment: I'm not install grub in /dev/sda because I think it will destroy my boot loader Windows 10? So, I'm installed grub on /dev/sda5 where the sda5 is ext4 (Elementary OS install location).

Comment: Grub can handle Windows and elementary OS normally, you could have installed boot loader for both OS

Comment: So, I must install grub on /dev/sda ONLY? The path looks like on Parent of SDA?

Answer (score 1):

Seems more like a boot loader issue. Grub should be installed on /dev/sda
Try the following

1. Create a bootable disk with Supergrub [link](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/) using WinISO or PowerISO or any similar software in your USB stick.
2. Boot the Supergrub from USB. Supergrup auto-detects all the OS installed on  your disks. Select the corresponding volume where elementary OS is installed.
3. Run the following commands in your elementary OS terminal

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   ```
4. Reboot.

Comment: But before this problem, my Elementary works good. I'm installed grub on /dev/sda5 not problem. The problem accur when I updated Loki to latest update. So, I'm do fresh install Loki with update on the go with Wifi internet. When finished, restart, can't see splash screen again and can't start my Loki...

Comment: Did u try the above steps? As I can say that, it was somehow able to detect the bootloader on /dev/sda5 prior to install and after update it might have gone corrupted.
If the problem is with wrong installation of kernel itself, then at least grub would have been loaded